# Why is it important for a correlation matrix to be positive semidefinite?

Tags: matrices, statistics, correlation, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Now I understand the definition of positive semidefiniteness but I am struggling to understand as to why a Correlation matrix must be positive semidefinite. What are the effects of negative eigenvalues in relation to correlation matrices?

Comment: Do you consider important for a variance to be non-negative ?

Comment: Are you interested in the sample correlation matrix for a data set or the theoretical correlation matrix for a vector of random variables with a joint distribution?

Comment: I am looking into the sample correlation matrix for a data set.

Comment: but either will be very helpful @BrianBorchers

Comment: If it is not PSD you can create a random variable that has negative variance. As an applied example consider the case of returns of $N$ stocks. If the correlation matrix is not PSD you can create a stock portfolio that has negative variance. But variance is $\geq 0$ by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that I've written this answer in terms of covariance matrices, but a correlation matrix is simply a scaled covariance matrix where

$\rho_{i,j}=\frac{C_{i,j}}{\sqrt{C_{i,i}} \sqrt{C_{j,j}}}$.

It's relatively easy to show that $C$ is positive semidefinite if and only if $\rho$ is positive semidefinite.

This answer is written in two parts because the term "covariance matrix" is sometimes used for the sample covariance matrix of a data set and other times for the theoretical covariance matrix of jointly distributed random variables.

First, the sample covariance.

Given a sequence of data vectors $x^{(1)}$, $x^{(2)}$, $\ldots$, $x^{(n)}$,
Let $X$ be the matrix whose columns are $x^{(1)}$, $x^{(2)}$, $\ldots$, $x^{(n)}$.

$X=\left[ x^{(1)}, x^{(2)}, \ldots x^{(n)} \right] $.

The sample mean is

$\bar{x}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x^{(i)}}{n}$.

It's convenient to define

$\bar{X}=\bar{x}\left[1, 1, \ldots, 1 \right]$

to get a matrix whose columns are each $\bar{x}$.

The sample covariance matrix is

$C=\frac{1}{n-1} \left( XX^{T} - \bar{X}\bar{X}^{T} \right)$.

To see that this matrix is positive semidefinite, take any vector $z$ in $R^{n}$.  Then

$z^{T}Cz=\frac{1}{n-1} (z^{T}(X-\bar{X}))^{T}((X-\bar{X})z$.

$z^{T}Cz=\frac{1}{n-1} ((X-\bar{X})z)^{T}((X-\bar{X})z)=\frac{1}{n-1}\| (X-\bar{X})z \|_{2}^{2} \geq 0$.

Thus $C$ is positive semidefinite.

Note that, in practice, particularly if $n$ is smaller than the dimension of the vectors $x$, $C$ can be numerically singular and might have what appear to be small negative eigenvalues.

Next, the covariance matrix of a jointly distributed vector of random variables.

Suppose that the random variables $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$, $\ldots$, $X_{n}$ are jointly distributed.  We'll assume that $E[X]=0$, but it's an easy exercise to extend this to a nonzero mean $\mu$.  Then

$\mbox{Cov}(X)=C=E[XX^{T}]$.

To show that $C$ is positive semidefinite, take any vector $z$ in $R^{n}$, and consider the random variable

$W=z^{T}X=z_{1}X_{1}+z_{2}X_{2}+\ldots+z_{n}X_{n}$.

Since $E[X^{(i)}]=0$, $E[W]=0$, and

$\mbox{Var}(W)=E[W^{2}]$.

$\mbox{Var}(W)=E[(z^{T}X)^{2}]=E[z^{T}XX^{T}z]$.

$\mbox{Var}(W)=z^{T}Cz$.

But the variance of every random variable is greater than or equal to 0, so

$\mbox{Var}(W)=z^{T}Cz \geq 0$.

In practice, we usually try to avoid working with covariance matrices that are positive semidefinite but singular and prefer to work with covariance matrices that are actually positive definite.

Comment: this may be a simple question but can I ask how did you get your definition of the sample covariance matrix? I thought it would of been the summation of $(X-\bar{X})(X-\bar{X})^T$

Comment: $(X-\bar{X})(X-\bar{X})^{T}=XX^{T}-\bar{X}\bar{X}^{T}$.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that a correlation matrix is positive-semidefinite (p.s.d.) is a property, not a desired attribute. Note that this is a theoretical fact, some algorithms may generate matrices with negative eigenvalues due to computational error and floating-point error.

Now let's take this discussion one step back so we can understand it better after.
The correlation matrix is part of a decompositon of the covariance matrix as shown below
$$
\Sigma = \operatorname{diag}(\sigma) C \operatorname{diag}(\sigma)
$$
where $\operatorname{diag}(\sigma)$ is a diagonal matrix with the standard deviations as it's entries.
Also notice that a p.s.d. matrix satisfy the following:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \; x^\top\Sigma x \geq 0$$

A useful fact about p.s.d. matrices that comes from the above statement is that there diagonal elements $\sigma_{ii}$ are greater or equal to $0$. Just choose $x_j=0$ if $j \not = i$ and $x_j=1$ if $j = i$, this gives $\sigma_{ii}\geq 0$.

So, we know the correlation matrix is p.s.d.. What does that mean?

Notice that if $C$ isn't p.s.d. you may get negative variances in the diagonal as pointed out by user @leonbloy in the comments. Notice that $C$ p.s.d implies $\Sigma$ p.s.d becase for every non-singular matrix $P$, transformations of the form $P\Sigma P$ are p.s.d.

Other interesting property is that if $\Sigma$ is p.s.d. then $\Sigma^{-1}$ is p.s.d. .
Which leads us to another problematic fact, we can't guarantee the following expression is positive neither convex
$$
(y-\mu)^\top\Sigma^{-1}(y-\mu)
$$
This is a commonly encountered expression in statistics known as mahalanobis distance and it's also encountered in the multivariate gaussian distribution. Let $X$ be a $MVN(\boldsymbol\mu, \boldsymbol\Sigma)$ then it's density is given by

$$f_{\mathbf X}(x_1,\ldots,x_k) = \frac{\exp\left(-\frac 1 2 ({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})^\mathrm{T}{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})\right)}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^k|\boldsymbol\Sigma|}}$$

Notice that the best case would be positive-definite $C$ because p.s.d. lets one or more variables be constant (A $0$ in the diagonal means a degenerate dimension and thus it's better to work in $N-1$ dimensions) or a linear combination of others and the $MVN$ pdf also becomes undefined.

Comment: thank you for relating it back to correlation!

Comment: Note that the MVN pdf is undefined if the covariance matrix is not positive definite (the determinant of $\Sigma$ in the denominator is 0$.  You really want $\Sigma$ to be positive definite, not just PSD.

Comment: Yes! If you have p.s.d then one or more dimensions may be degenerate! Thx, for the reminder!

Comment: I made some changes to improve the answer, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: "It means one or more variables are constant." isn't correct.  It means that there is linear dependence among the random variables, which can occur in lots of ways.  For example, consider the bivariate normal distribution with $X_{2}=-X_{1}$ and $\Sigma=[1 \;  -1 ; -1  \;1]$.

Comment: I mean if the $i-th$ diagonal element is equal to $0$ then $x_i$ is constant, that can happen if we let covariance be p.s.d. instead of p.d . but i added the case you pointed out thx